# Is it possible to use string elements as input in sklearn?

Tags: python, import, scikit-learn, data-visualization, bioinformatics

I am trying to analyze my data using sklearn and see if there is some correlation between elements. My data set is a short protein motif which is quite diverse in sequence. My input looks like this:

```
  1p 2p 3p 4p 5p               genus
0  T  V  H  F  K  Enterobacteriaceae
1  T  V  M  F  M         Escherichia
2  E  I  H  V  K  Enterobacteriaceae
3  K  L  M  F  K  Enterobacteriaceae
```

There are 20 different letter possibilities at positions 1-5.

I wanted to use similar approach as it was shown in the sklearn Iris set to check dependencies between amino acids in different positions and bacterial genus. In the other words, I want to see if sequence of letters is genus specific and if letter at single position is somehow related to letters in other positions.

Problem is, as far as I know, only numbers can be used as an input for sklearn. I tried to subsitute letters with numbers: from 1e-10 to 1e10 for each individual letter, but I had problems with data visualization later. I hope there is other, way more efficient way of using this kind of input data. I would be very grateful for some hints. Thanks!

Comment: Sklearn needs numerical data, you have to convert to them. In visualization you can specify xlabel or ylabel specifically in matplotlib.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest the use of [`LabelEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

df
  1p 2p 3p 4p 5p               genus
0  T  V  H  F  K  Enterobacteriaceae
1  T  V  M  F  M         Escherichia
2  E  I  H  V  K  Enterobacteriaceae
3  K  L  M  F  K  Enterobacteriaceae
le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit(np.unique(df.drop('genus', axis=1)))
X = np.array([le.transform(samp) for samp in df.drop('genus', axis=1).values])
X
array([[7, 8, 2, 1, 4],
       [7, 8, 6, 1, 6],
       [0, 3, 2, 8, 4],
       [4, 5, 6, 1, 4]])
```

From there you should be able to check the correlations.

Comment: One more question: Is it possible, easily, to decompose the numerical data back to string elements?

Comment: @Dawid you can use the inverse_transform method to go from labels to category names